# Need to understand hash of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I came to know that we can create hash of hashes as below:

```
Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new}
```

But I dont understand whether the key and value getting converted as hash. Can someone explain me in brief about this.

Comment: You can check some [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)

Comment: I don't get your question. What is it you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `hash` this way, ruby set the default value on every key in hash to new hash and save it.

sample

```
h = Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new}

h[:foo]
# => {}
p h
# => {:foo=>{}}
```

insted of define only default value

```
h = Hash.new({})

h[:foo]
# => {}
p h
# => {}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understood very well