# Return elements from one array, based on values from another one

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Writing a plugin for Jekyll, I am stucked at some ruby related code as I am not yet familiar on
how to do `.select`, `.map` and all their friends on arrays (except for simple one array cases)

So my problem now is, having this as an array of docs, with their related `sha1sum` codes:

```
[
    [
        #<Jekyll::Document _projects/1st-project.md collection=projects>,
        "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79"
    ],
    [
        #<Jekyll::Document _posts/2nd-project.markdown collection=posts>,
        "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"
    ],
    [
        #<Jekyll::Document _posts/3rd-project.markdown collection=posts>,
        "37bf18464b00c9a808436853bc6d868aff218eb6"
    ],
    ...
    ...
]
```

And on the other side, the hash of linkage groups like so:

```
{
    "linkage_groups"=>
    [
        {
            "group_name"=>"test1",
            "sha1_sums"=> [
                "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8",
                "37bf18464b00c9a808436853bc6d868aff218eb6"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group_name"=>"test1",
            "sha1_sums"=> [
                "154c255d59e6063fc609ade2254dc1b09d1de8ab",
                "3e9ef9f059786888e39df608d104263cf0fdae76"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I be able to cycle through these groups one at a time, and return for each group of `sha1_sums` docs from the above
array where `sha1_sum` of a document is present in a particular group.

Expected output would be an array of hashes for each of the groups, holding
docs which fulfill the condition, on their `sha1_sum` being present in a group:

Ex. 2nd and 3rd project fulfill the condition because their `sha's` are in a group named `test1`

```
[
    {
        "test1" => [#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2nd-project.markdown collection=posts>, #<Jekyll::Document _posts/3rd-project.markdown collection=posts]
    },
    {
        "test2" => [..., ...]
    },
    {
        "test3" => [..., ...]
    },
    ...
]
```

As of reply from @Lukas Baliak -

Here is what I am getting in case of both hashes belonging to the same group:

```
{
    "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"=>"test1",
    "b673be35ad73ab48da23b271ab0dda95ea07c905"=>"test1",
    "154c255d59e6063fc609ade2254dc1b09d1de8ab"=>"test2",
    "3e9ef9f059786888e39df608d104263cf0fdae76"=>"test2"
}

[
    [
        #<Jekyll::Document _projects/my-first-project.md collection=projects>,
        "b673be35ad73ab48da23b271ab0dda95ea07c905"
    ],
    [
        #<Jekyll::Document _posts/2016-06-05-one-more-post.markdown collection=posts>,
        "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"
    ]
]

{
    "test1"=> [#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2016-06-05-one-more-post.markdown collection=posts>, "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"]
}
```

Only one document is listed, why? Where is `b673be35ad73ab48da23b271ab0dda95ea07c905`?

Comment: Show us some expected output.

Comment: @LukasBaliak please see the newest addition above.

Comment: Ok, i edit my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I preffer to use simple data structures, so i "migrate" groups to `Hash`

doc

```
doc = [
  [
    "#<Jekyll::Document _projects/my-first-project.md collection=projects>",
    "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79"
  ],
  [
   "#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2016-06-05-one-more-post.markdown collection=posts>",
    "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"
  ]
]
```

group_config

```
group_config = {
  "linkage_groups" => [
    {
      "group_name" => "test1",
      "sha1_sums" => [
        "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8",
        "b673be35ad73ab48da23b271ab0dda95ea07c905"
      ]
    },
    {
      "group_name" => "test2",
      "sha1_sums" => [
        "154c255d59e6063fc609ade2254dc1b09d1de8ab",
        "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Migrate to `Hash`

```
groups = group_config["linkage_groups"].each_with_object({}) do |h, exp|
  h["sha1_sums"].each { |sha1| exp[sha1] = h["group_name"] }
end
```

export groups

```
p groups

# {
#   "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8" => "test1",
#   "b673be35ad73ab48da23b271ab0dda95ea07c905" => "test1",
#   "154c255d59e6063fc609ade2254dc1b09d1de8ab" => "test2",
#   "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79" => "test2"
# }
```

And process to generate hash structure

```
export = doc.each_with_object({}) do |arr, exp|
  exp[groups[arr[1]]] = arr
end
```

output

```
p export

# {
#   "test2" => ["#<Jekyll::Document _projects/my-first-project.md collection=projects>", "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79"],
#   "test1" => ["#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2016-06-05-one-more-post.markdown collection=posts>", "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"]
# }
```

**EDIT:**

If you need more then one use this modification

```
export = doc.each_with_object(Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = []}) do |arr, exp|
  exp[groups[arr[1]]] << arr
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, if you need one sha1_hash in to more groups may be you can use this update.

```
groups = group_config["linkage_groups"].each_with_object(Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = [] }) do |h, exp|
  h["sha1_sums"].each { |sha1| exp[sha1] << h["group_name"] }
end
```

groups

```
p groups

# {
#   "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8" => ["test1"],
#   "b673be35ad73ab48da23b271ab0dda95ea07c905" => ["test1"],
#   "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79" => ["test1", "test2"],
#   "154c255d59e6063fc609ade2254dc1b09d1de8ab" => ["test2"]
# }
```

process

```
export = doc.each_with_object(Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = [] }) do |arr, exp|
  groups[arr[1]].each { |group| exp[group] << arr }
end
```

output

```
p export

# {
#   "test1" => [
#     ["#<Jekyll::Document _projects/my-first-project.md collection=projects>", "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79"],
#     ["#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2016-06-05-one-more-post.markdown collection=posts>", "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"]
#   ],
#   "test2" => [
#     ["#<Jekyll::Document _projects/my-first-project.md collection=projects>", "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79"],
#     ["#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2016-06-0s-one-more-post.markdown collection=posts>", "154c255d59e6063fc609ade2254dc1b09d1de8ab"]
#   ]
# }
```

I hope this will helps.

Comment: Great, now just to wrap my head around these `each_with_object` things.. Not getting it.

Comment: Actually I got the first ones with an `{}`, but  the last one with `Hash.new{}` is confusing.

Comment: @branquito maybe this will helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064209/how-is-each-with-object-supposed-to-work and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679425/need-to-understand-hash-of-hashes-in-ruby/

Comment: another problem ocurred, your first hash migration does not allow for `sha1
sums` to repeat themselves in different combinations, which is the whole
purpose I am doing this, to have posibility to have in say `test1` group
`9ce...` and `3bf...`, and in `test2` say `9ce...` and `4a8...`
But right now that `9ce` as `[ index ]` gets overwritten next time when it is encountered..
Is there some easy fix to this!? thanks.

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: And its possible to have one sha1 hash inside two groups ?

Comment: exactly, but no duplicate hashes within the same group.

Comment: you've been of a great help

Comment: I am glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are not very clear in your question. Sometimes it helps to be detailed about what output is expected for which input. I assume the `array` contains the `Document/Sha1` pairs and that `hash` contains the `linkage_groups`.

The `hash` looks like this:

```
{"linkage_groups"=>[{"group_name"=>"test1", "sha1_sums"=>["ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8", "b673be35ad73ab48da23b271ab0dda95ea07c905"]}, {"group_name"=>"test1", "sha1_sums"=>["154c255d59e6063fc609ade2254dc1b09d1de8ab", "3e9ef9f059786888e39df608d104263cf0fdae76"]}]}
```

And the `array` looks like this:

```
[["Document1", "8f918a3d8263a957c206a9864d3507aaa5277a79"], ["Document2", "ca81eda5d49100bdf23db16fe1c9d17040fd33f8"]]
```

I'd try something like this:

```
hash["linkage_groups"].each { |group|  // for each linkage group
    group["sha1_sums"].each { |sha1|   // for each sha1 in group
        array.each { |array_element|   // for each array element (which itself is an array of document/sha1 pairs
            if array_element.include?(sha1) then 
                puts "#{array_element[0]} found in #{group["group_name"]} with #{group["sha1"]}" 
            end 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I leave it up to you to manage how to return the elements according to your needs.